# Getting error with multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

So, I decided I was going to make a little ASCII art game, however, when I declared the board, I get the error "array type has incomplete element type." Any idea on how to fix this?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int height = 10;
int width = 12;
char board[][] =            {{'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                             {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}};

void printBoard(void) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would probably initialize ("initialize") that with something other than a billion separate hyphens.

Comment: You can only leave the most significant dimension free.

Comment: Both row, column size is not optional. Only row is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the outer most dimension can be left unspecified.

Change your array definition to:

```
char board[][12] =  { ...};
```

Same applies if you are using a 3D array for example:

```
char board3D[][12][12] =  { ...}; // OK
char board3D[][][12] =  { ...}; // Not OK
char board3D[][][] =  { ...}; // Not OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to add items dynamically to the multidimensional array but in c `char board[][] =`   won't work you need to specify at the length `char board[][12] =`.

Answer (score 0):

It would work better to declare your array like this:

```
#define height 10
#define width  12
char board[height][width];
```

and then initialize it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < width; j++){
        board[i][j] = '-';
    }
}
```

Then you can print it out with your "printBoard()" function.
Hope this helps!